# Postman can't access my Symfony "PUT" Route properly

Tags: symfony, routes, postman, put

I've looked a lot of places and I can't get my PUT route to work. I just want my PUT route to edit the id of the article specified in the route, here's what my route looks like:

```
/**
 * @return Response
 * @Route("/{id}", methods={"PUT"})
 * @param $id
 * @param Request $request
 */
public function edit($id, Request $request): Response
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $article = $em->find(Article::class,$id);
    if ($article)
    {
        $request->request->add(["article" => json_decode($request->getContent(), true)]);
        $form = $this->createForm(ArticleType::class, new Article())->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
        {
            $article->setNom($form["nom"]->getData());
            $article->setDescription($form["description"]->getData());
            $article->setPrix($form["prix"]->getData());
            $em->refresh($article);
            return $this->json($article, 205);
        }
        return $this->json(["error" => "Bad request"], 400);
    }
    return $this->json(["error" => "Not Found"], 404);
}
```

It seems good to me but not for Postman although it's not completely bad as it DOES get into the code! But it returns the 400 error code so I think it means it doesn't go inside the second if and I don't get why as I used a similar setup for my DELETE route. I'm trying my best to learn how routing works but for the PUT, I'm at a loss even after hours of searching so some help would really be appreciated!

If needed, here's the rest of the Controller code. And yes, I did tell my subscriber to allow "PUT" routes. Also, it's my first post, I hope it's good enough for this site's standards and loads of thanks to anyone willing to give me a little of their time!

```
    <?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Article;
use App\Form\ArticleType;
use App\Repository\ArticleRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * Class ArticleController
 * @package App\Controller
 * @Route("/article")
 */
class ArticleController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @return Response
     * @Route("/", methods={"GET"})
     * @param ArticleRepository $repository
     */
    public function index(ArticleRepository $repository): Response
    {
        return $this->json($repository->findAll());
    }

    /**
     * @return Response
     * @Route("/{id}", methods={"GET"})
     * @param $id
     */
    public function find($id): Response
    {
        $em = $this->getdoctrine()->getmanager();
        $article = $em->find(Article::class,$id);
        if ($article)
        {
            return $this->json($article, 201);
        }
        return $this->json(["error" => "Not Found"], 404);
    }

    /**
     * @return Response
     * @Route("/", methods={"POST"})
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function new(Request $request): Response
    {
        $request->request->add(["article" => json_decode($request->getContent(), true)]);
        $form = $this->createForm(ArticleType::class, new Article())->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($form->getData());
            $em->flush();
            return $this->json($form->getData(), 201);
        }
        return $this->json(["error" => "Bad request"], 400);
    }

    /**
     * @return Response
     * @Route("/{id}", methods={"DELETE"})
     * @param $id
     */
    public function delete($id): Response
    {
        $em = $this->getdoctrine()->getmanager();
        $article = $em->find(Article::class,$id);
        if ($article)
        {
            $em->remove($article);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->json($article, 205);
        }
        return $this->json(["error" => "Not Found"], 404);
    }
```

Also, here's my Postman Request

```
{
    "nom": "test",
    "description": "description test",
    "prix": 7
}
```

And here's ArticleType.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Article;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ArticleType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nom')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('prix')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Article::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should probably just use https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/direct_submit.html ... also you should probably check that `$request->getContent()` does contain the content, you expect. finally: your 400 line should - at least for development purposes - return the actual error messages from form validation ;o)

Comment: Is the error what Inmarelibero suggested? It returned a lenghty message viewable here: https://www.mediafire.com/file/4llywfhbw0qwr17/dump.txt/file
I checked and $request->getContent() does have my content! 
And finally, it seems to be similar but I don't understand what's the "Task()" doing here. Thanks!

Comment: The Task is like your Article. the file you uploaded contains an empty form error iterator, it seems (you can rename the extension to .html and view it in the browser). $request->getContent() is empty. postman is quite powerful and you can send essentially invalid requests. you have to check how you want to encode the data (raw, form-encoded, ...) and if raw, you have to send the correct content-type (application/json) and stuff. it's a common problem I feel with postman. I have no specific advice, I don't use postman, I'd rather use curl ;oD POST request is better defined btw (encoding)

Comment: I did the application/json thing! And as I said it receives the content and Postman even works on GET, POST & DELETE! Just not on PUT and that's annoying. Like the rest works, just not the PUT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest a couple of things:

1. separate `if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())` into some more readable and debuggable:

```
if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
  if ($form->isValid()) {
    ...
  }
}
```

in this way you can better check if the form was submitted and/or it was valid

can you please paste the request body you are sending through Postman? and also the ArticleType.php class

2. never ever modify the original request like `$request->request->add(["article" => json_decode($request->getContent(), true)]);`

try to find other ways; what do you need this for?

Comment: OK thanks I'll do that and look into your answer and Jakumi's comment.
This is a simple PUT where I just replace existing data of a specific ID
I'll add my Postman & ArticleType.php into the original post!

Comment: my guess here is that you are missing the csrf token, which usage must be explicitly disabled when using api (did you already disable it?)

Comment: also, did you separate isSubmitted() and isValid()?

can you paste here the output of dump(form->getErrors()) ?

Comment: having isSubmitted and isValid in one if clause is btw best practice and very very common in symfony code (it's also in their docs and tutorials)

Comment: it's in the doc for simplicity, if it was a best practice a method named ->isSubmittedAndValid() would exist

separation is useful in this case and, for example, if you have to add a flash message if the form is submitted but not valid

Comment: OK so the error is OnSubmitted
The dump was very lengthy so you can download it here: https://www.mediafire.com/file/4llywfhbw0qwr17/dump.txt/file
Finally, what's wrong with this line cuz it works on a POST request?

Comment: forms have names, in this case the name is "article": you can see it in the dump you pasted (form->name)

this is because of the method Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypegetBlockPrefix(), which prints basically the name of the handled entity if you don't overwrite it

you have 2 options here:

Comment: 1) submit

`{"article": {"nom": "test", "description": "description test", "prix": 7}}`

instead of

`{"nom": "test", "description": "description test", "prix": 7}`

because otherwise the form will never be submitted. It's like handling the field `<input type="text" name="article[nom]" /> submitted by a regular html form

Comment: 2) in `ArticleType.php`, define the method:

`public function getBlockPrefix() { return null; }`

and submit

`{ "nom": "test", "description": "description test", "prix": 7 }`

with Postman, it should work fine and you can check it printing `dump($form->isSubmitted())` that should return `true` now

Comment: personally I prefer 2), if you are designing APIs

sorry for the messy code layout, stackoverflow doesn't let me enter markdown in answers. tell me if it's clear

Comment: 1 *seems* to work but it doesn't actually edit on the database and returns status 200 although I specified to return status 205 so that's not right...
2 gives me a different error however with status 500: <!-- Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory::createNamedBuilder() must be of the type string, null given, called in C:\Users\Utilisateur\Documents\M2i\sell-o-matic\vendor\symfony\form\FormFactory.php on line 52 (500 Internal Server Error) -->

Comment: I've changed "return null" to "return 'article'" and same error as number one. And my mistake, it seems there's still an error on the "IsSubmitted" so I guess that didn't help?

Comment: I was able to make it work by using : "$form = $this->createForm(ArticleType::class, new Article(), array(
                'method' => 'put'
            ))->handleRequest($request);" instead but the sets don't seem to work nonetheless, it doesn't modify the specified database entry.. Are my setters wrongly used?

Comment: the third argument, `array('method' => 'put')` doesn't have any sense, because you put there the database entry you want to edit

in this case you must use `$form = $this->createForm(ArticleType::class, $article)->handleRequest($request);`

otherwise a new entity will always be created

Answer (score 0):

Finally it works, thanks so much to everyone!
Here's what ended up working for me:

```
/**
 * @return Response
 * @Route("/{id}", methods={"PUT"})
 * @param $id
 * @param Request $request
 */
public function edit($id, Request $request): Response
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $article = $em->find(Article::class,$id);
    if ($article)
    {
        $request->request->add(["article" => json_decode($request->getContent(), true)]);
        $form = $this->createForm(ArticleType::class, $article, array(
            'method' => 'put'
        ))->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted())
        {
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($form->getData());
                $em->flush();
                return $this->json($form->getData(), 201);
            }
            return $this->json(["error" => "on isValid"], 400, array($form->getErrors()));
        }
        return $this->json(["error" => "on isSubmitted"], 400, array($form->getErrors()));
    }
    return $this->json(["error" => "Not Found"], 404);
}
```

Without the 'method' => 'put' it doesn't seem to work.. And I checked it does replace the data of the corresponding ID with this! Thank you so much for your support everyone and have a great day!!